# Java, Regex, strip unwanted characters [trailing, leading, between]

Tags: java, regex

i need help for an regular expression to strip unwanted characters from an String (in Java).
I solved this issue with 4 regular expression following each other. 
The replace will be called many times [peeks: 50+ times/sec] it and decreases performance.
But i think it sure possible with an single expression, so the performance will be increased a little.

The TestString is

```
"   ! ... my-Cruc i@l_\\/Disp lay.Na#m3 ?;()!    "
```

The tasks i like to perform with regex

- Remove all leading non-alpha charcters – [Beginning of String]
- Remove all trailing non-alphanumeric characters – [End of String]
- Remove all non-alphanumeric characters(except [_-.]) between

So the result will be

```
my-Cruil_Display.Nam3
```

The Problem is the switch between, the built-in patterns Alnum and alpha, depending on position in string (beginning, end) and the exception characters [_-.] between them.

I tried this many times in the last few days, but i do not get it to work.
Removing leading non-alpha characters is working with regex

```
^([^\\p{Alpha}]+)?
```

But if i append the „between“ it doesnt work longer anything

Removing trailing non-alpha charcter with regex

```
([^\\p{Alnum}]+$)
```

is working , but not im combination with all other regex

One of the last tries are

```
(^[^\\p{Alpha}]+)?[^\\p{Alnum}\\._-]+([^\\p{Alnum}]+$)
```

Can anyone help to get this working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^\P{Alpha}+|\P{Alnum}+$|[^\p{Alnum}_.-]
```

Java:

```
s = s.replaceAll("^\\P{Alpha}+|\\P{Alnum}+$|[^\\p{Alnum}_.-]", "");
```

Or, to make it Unicode aware, add the `(?U)` flag:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?U)^\\P{Alpha}+|\\P{Alnum}+$|[^\\p{Alnum}_.-]", "");
```

**Details**

- `^\P{Alpha}+` - any 1 or more chars other than alphabetic chars at the start of the string
- `|` - or
- `\P{Alnum}+$` - any 1 or more chars other than alphanumeric chars at the end of the string
- `|` - or
- `[^\p{Alnum}_.-]` - any char other than alphanumeric, `_`, `.` and `-` chars anywhere in the string

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GnlwGb/1).

Comment: sincerelest thanks. i spent many hours with that, and you got it in few minutes. Little bit frustrating .. but get confirmed not showing the woods for trees.